# How do I get Optimistic Concurrency to fail with detached objects in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency

Our project is currently migrating to EF(and away from Stored Procs), and one of the enhancements(we're adding to the architecture) is using Optimistic Concurrency when users save data to the database(we currently don't have this feature).  I'm having problems getting EF to fail when it should.  In other words when two users open the same record, each make changes and attempts to save those changes the first to save update the record, and the second would get an error message.  I created a simple example to illustrate my problem.

In the database I have the following table(and insert test data):

```
Create Table Work
(
 Id int identity(1,1) Primary Key
 ,UserIdAssignTo int null
 ,RowVer RowVersion not null
)
Insert Into Work(UserIdAssignTo)Values(1)
```

I created an EF file (.edmx) and drag/drop the table, above, onto the canvas.  I updated the properties on the property/column RowVer as follows:

- RowVer Property/Column
- Concurrency Mode: Fixed
- Getter/Setter are both Public
- Nullable: False
- Store Generated: Computed
- Type: Binary

I have an object that will retrieve and update the table like below:

```
public class Work
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int? UserIdAssignTo { get; set; }
  public byte[] Version { get; set; }

  private string _conn = String.Empty;

  public  WorkData() 
  {
    _conn = GetConnectionsString();
  }

  public void GetById(int WorkID)
  {
    using (SQL context = new SQL(_conn))
    {
        Work fromDb = context.Works.FirstOrDefault(db => db.Id == WorkID);

        if (fromDb != null)
        {
            Id = fromDb.Id;
            UserIdAssignTo = fromDb.UserIdAssignTo;
            Version = fromDb.RowVer;
        }
    }
  }

  public void Update()
  {
    using (SQL context = new SQL(_conn))
    {
        Work fromDb = context.Works.FirstOrDefault(db => db.Id == Id);

        if (fromDb != null)
        {
            fromDb.UserIdAssignTo = UserIdAssignTo;
            fromDb.RowVer = Version;

            context.SaveChanges();

            UserIdAssignTo = fromDb.UserIdAssignTo;
            Version = fromDb.RowVer;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I developed a test case to expose the error I'm getting:

```
[Test]
public void ConcurencyDataTest()
{
    WorkData first = new WorkData();
    first.GetById(1);
    WorkData second = new WorkData();
    second.GetById(1);

    first.UserIdAssignTo = null;
    first.Update();

    second.UserIdAssignTo = 1;
    second.Update();  // I should get an exception b/c the object is outdated
}
```

After both "first" and "second" object call the GetById(1) method, their RowVer property is the same for both objects(as expected).

I ran SQL profiler when I executed this test

The below is when the "first" object called Update method

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Work]
set [UserIdAssignTo] = null
where (([Id] = @0) and ([RowVer] = @1))
select [RowVer]
from [dbo].[Work]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = @0',N'@0 int,@1 binary(8)',@0=1,@1=0x00000000024E6E2
```

Note the @1 parameter, both the "first" and "second" object should have that in memory and use it when update

When second.Update was called, the SQL profiler recorded this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Work]
set [UserIdAssignTo] = @0
where (([Id] = @1) and ([RowVer] = @2))
select [RowVer]
from [dbo].[Work]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = @1',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 binary(8)',@0=1,@1=1,@2=0x00000000024E6E2F
```

Note the @1 parameter has changed to the new value(after "first" updated), when it should be the old value that was held by the object "second"(the old value is 0x00000000024E6E2).  I don't understand how it got changed and I'm a little confused on how to properly implement first write concurrency through EF.

The results I'm actually getting is the "second" object is successfully updating the table, when it should be failing.

Edit: This to simulate using an N-tier architecture.  I'm trying to update with detached objects.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because in your update method you retrieve the object again from the context which would get the current value of RowVer.  Since it is computed I don't think setting it back to the previous version would work.  So when it updates it does have the current value of RowVer that is in the table.

I think you instead would need to attach or add the object to the context.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx